# For Loop - Perform Action on Row Based on Cell Value (Apps Script)

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm relatively new to Javascript, particularly loops, but I have some code that I think should be working. It is not returning any errors but when I run it nothing happens. Stack Overflow helps me solve pretty much everything I need to, but after hours of browsing and experimenting I'm still stumped.

I think the issue is in my loop. What I'm trying to accomplish (insert a range of formulas and set it as a value) isn't that straight forward, but even when I try to simply print "B" to the test cell I still get no result.

Thanks in advance.

```
function Translate(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("English Responses");
var formulasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Formula Range");
var lastRow = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
var formularange = formulasheet.getRange(1, 2, 1, 18);
var formulas = formularange.getFormulasR1C1();

for (var i = 1; i <= lastRow; i++){
var finishedRange = sourceSheet.getRange([i], 1);
var finishedValue = finishedRange.getValues();

var emptyCheckRange = sourceSheet.getRange([i], 2);
var emptyCheckValue = finishedRange.getValues();

var translationRange = sourceSheet.getRange([i], 2, 1, 18);

if (finishedValue =='A' && emptyCheckValue == ''){  
//translationRange.setFormulas(formulas);   
emptyCheckValue.setValue("B");
//translationRange.copyValuesToRange(sourceSheet, 1, 18, 1, 1); 
}}}
```

Comment: Have you tried confirming that your `if` statement logic is correct? I don't know if Google Apps Scripts let you use `console.log()` statements to record errors in your browser developer tools, but you could try adding `alert()` statements to confirm the values of `finishedValue` and `emptyCheckValue` to see if they're coming out as you expect.

Comment: Thank you, this was excellent advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to GAS documentation, the 'getValues()' method of the 'Range' class returns the two-dimensional array of values. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues The issue is this line right here:

```
var emptyCheckValue = finishedRange.getValues();
```

If the value entered in the cell is 'A', the 'emptyCheckValue' will be

```
[['A']] //Each inner array corresponds to a row in your spreadsheet.
```

Had you called 'getValue()' instead of 'getValues()', it would've been just 'A'. I think you can now see why calling 'setValue()' on 'emptyCheckValue' fails. Just like the 'getValue(s)()' method, it belongs to the Range class that's unique to Google Sheets, so you need to call this method on the instance of an object of type 'Range'.

Your 'emptyCheckValue' variable is a JS array, so you are limited to the methods in Array.prototype. To make changes to the sheet, the variable left of the dot must belong to 'Range' class, e.g.

```
finishedRange.setValue('B');
// or
finishedRange.setValues([['B']]); //the 2d array must match the size of the range
```

Finally, iterating over the values like this is very ineffective and costly performance-wise:

```
var finishedRange = sourceSheet.getRange([i], 1); //brackets around 'i' are not necessary either
```

You can simply read the entire data range into a 2d array, process the values, and write them to sheet in one action. Here's how to do it for 1 column in a sheet:

```
var valuesArray = sourceSheet.getRange(startRow, startCol, sourcesheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();


var processedValuesArray = valuesArray.map(function(row){

   var value = row[0];
   //do something with value

return value;

});
```

You could then get the desired target range of matching dimensions and write new values to it:

```
targetRange.setValues(processedValuesArray);
```

Comment: Probably a super dumb question, but do I run a loop iterating through the rows or is the whole point not to do that? Thanks

Comment: I don't suppose this is anything close to what you were getting at: setTranslations(){
var range = sourceSheet.getRange(2,1,15,2).getValues();
var colA = range[0];
var blank = range[1];

  
for (var i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++){
var translationRange = sourceSheet.getRange(i, 2, 1, 16);
if (colA =="A" && blank == ""){ 
translationRange.setFormulas(formulas);   
Utilities.sleep(5000);  
range.copyValuesToRange(sourceSheet, 2, 17, 1, sourceSheet.getLastRow())
}}}

Comment: No, this seems to be slow and ineffective as you are calling GAS services inside a 'for' loop. You can get the range like this 'var range = sheet.getRange(startRow, startCol, numRows, numCols)' and retrieve the values by calling 'getValues()' on the range object. After iterating over the array of values and making the necessary changes, you can overwrite the entire range by simply feeding your updated array to the 'setValues()' method. No need to create a separate instance of the range object for each row in a sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop looks good. Your problem is in this line:

```
emptyCheckValue.setValue("B");
```

emptyCheckValue is a value and not a range, so setValue() won't work. It will work if you change it to:

```
emptyCheckRange.setValue("B");
```